# How to export a matrix with complex entries having arbitrary precision from Mathematica to Matlab?

Tags: matrix, export, matlab

I am trying to export a large matrix with complex entires having arbitrary precision (~ roughly 200 digits after the decimal point) from Mathematica to Matlab.

I have used `Export["data.mat", A]` where A is the matrix in Mathematica. MATLAB is able to read the matrix but the assigns a data type `complex double` to the entires resulting in a loss of precision.

I have also tried exporting it as a CSV file, by MATLAB, replaces most of the entires with `NaN`.

I understand this is more of a MATLAB question but I think there might me people here who have some experience in this regard, hence I thought of asking this here.

Is there any other data format that one can use, say, like `hdf5`?

Answer (score 8):

Matlab by default uses real numbers. So you can't use .mat. But you can use the Matlab symbolic toolbox as follows

Instead of doing this

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
r = N[Pi, 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Export["r.mat", r]
```

Then in Matlab doing

```
>> format long
>> S=load('r.mat')

S = 
  struct with fields:
    Expression1: 3.141592653589793
```

Do this

```
r = N[Pi, 100]
Export["r.dat", r]
```

And now in Matlab

```
>> fid=fopen('r.dat')
>> r=fgetl(fid)
'3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117068'
>> fclose(fid)
```

And now use Matlab's vpa with syms. vpa by default uses 32 decimal point, but you can use any value (that is why it is called vpa)

```
 >> rs=vpa(sym(r),100)

rs = 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117068
```

Now you can use `rs` variable and will have same number of decimal points as in Mathematica. But you will have to use Matlab symbolic toolbox (symengine).  Without this, obviously you can not do what you want since standard Matlab uses real machine numbers. (default is double)

https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html

https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html

> vpa(x) uses variable-precision arithmetic (arbitrary-precision
> floating-point numbers) to evaluate each element of the symbolic input
> x to at least d significant digits, where d is the value of the digits
> function. The default value of digits is 32.

So basically you save your data from Mathematica not to .mat file, but to a plain textfile, and then read the data into Matlab as strings, and then convert them to syms and use VPA to get same decimals stored in file.

You'd have to stay inside symbolic toolbox from now on to use these and do any computation on them as syms variables and *not* as Matlab variables.

You can't use these syms variables outside of the symengine. Once you move the data back to Matlab proper the arbitrary precision is lost.

This is one advantage of using Mathematica over Matlab, it is all in one environment.

Comment: I understand the idea. Let me test this out and get back to you! Thanks.

Comment: @noir1993 note it is `vpa(sym(r),100)`, I had copied the wrong line before. Corrected now.